# При компиляции plugins:maven выдает ошибку

Tags: java, maven

При компиляции plugins:maven выдает ошибку:

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project user-lib: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x2a9f8d47) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x2a9f8d47 -> [Help 1]
```

pom.xml

```
  <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring-boot-starter-test.version>2.3.2.RELEASE</spring-boot-starter-test.version>
    <junit-version>5.7.0</junit-version>
    <spring.version>5.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.12</lombok.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot-starter-test.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
          <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что это известный баг: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2681

Попробуй поставить ломбок последней версии: https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven

Comment: версия не рабочая .попробуйте установить другую.